# How to test a method which requires an external rest call?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I would like to unit test a method which logs in the user via an external access management infrastructure. I do not know how to mock the `Response response` object.

This is my code what I intend to test:

```
public String login(final String username, final String password) {
    String baseUrl = getOpenAMApiBaseUrl();
    String path = "/openam/json/authenticate";

    // Response NEEDS TO BE MOCKED SOMEHOW
    Response response = jaxClient.target(baseUrl + path)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .header(HttpHeaderField.OPENAM_USERNAME, username)
            .header(HttpHeaderField.OPENAM_PASSWORD, password)
            .post(Entity.json(null));

    int status = response.getStatus();
    String jsonResponse = response.readEntity(String.class);

    if (status == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
        try (JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonResponse))) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
            String token = jsonObject.getString("tokenId");
            LOGGER.info("{} have successfully logged in", username);
            return token;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            LOGGER.info("login failed, invalid json response for {}/{}", username, password);
            return null;
        }
    }

    String message = "an error occurred during logging in, http status: {}, user: {}/{}";
    if (status == Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode()) {
        message = "invalid credentials, http status: {}, user: {}/{}";
    }
    LOGGER.info(message, status, username, password);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? If yes, where is the code?

Comment: I do not have anything because I do not know how to mock the external rest call.

Comment: And what prevented you from reading tutorials on Mockito and trying? So far, you only dropped requirements ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ideally you would have to mock all the call starting from the `jaxClient.target` method but in this case due to a very long chain needed to produce a mock i would suggest one of two options:

**1) (preferrable)** - extract the creation of the Response to a new class that specializes only in that particular operation.

Then you would declare that class as the dependency of the class under test an simply inject a mock of it with the builder method configured to return a certain Response object.

**2)** You can create a package level method in your class like following:

```
Response buildResponse(){
    String baseUrl = getOpenAMApiBaseUrl();
    String path = "/openam/json/authenticate";

    // Response NEEDS TO BE MOCKED SOMEHOW
    Response response = jaxClient.target(baseUrl + path)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .header(HttpHeaderField.OPENAM_USERNAME, username)
            .header(HttpHeaderField.OPENAM_PASSWORD, password)
            .post(Entity.json(null));
}
```

Then @Spy your class under test and mock that method to return a Response that you desire:

```
@Spy
ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

@Mock
Response responseMock;

@Before
public void init(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void test(){
    doReturn(responseMock).when(classUnderTest).buildResponse();

    // Act

    classUnderTest.login(login,pass);

   // Assertions
}
```